# Adding row inside a row in repeat.?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am adding a row inside a row..Here is the scenario. On Click of add button i am adding a row.i know how to do that..I am able to do that.Now i want to add more rows inside that row using some different button i.e i have adding a row by clicking on main add row button.now i also have a different section inside that row where i can further add rows.

```
<apex:repeat value="{!wrapperList}" var="wra">
 <apex:pageBlock title="Consolidated Feed">
    <apex:pageBlockSection >
     <table>
           <tr>
             <td>
                <apex:inputField value="{!wra.conFeed.CPF_Quantity__c}"/>
             </td>
           </tr>
     </table>
   </apex:pageBlockSection>  
  </apex:pageBlock>  

     <apex:pageBlock title="test">

      <apex:commandButton action="{!addRowHex}" value="Add new section inside" reRender="hexSec" />
     <apex:pageBlockSection >

               <apex:repeat value="{!wra.excEnti}" var="wrEx">
                 <apex:inputField value="{!wrEx.Name}"/>
                 <apex:inputField value="{!wrEx.Hex_Code__c}"/>
              </apex:repeat>
     </apex:pageBlockSection>   
     </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:repeat>
```

**wrapper class**

```
public object1 conFeed{get;set;}
 public List<object2> excEnti{get;set;}
  public Integer counterWrap{get;set;}

 public wrapperClass(object1 conFeed,List<object2> excEnti)
 {
     this.conFeed=conFeed;
     this.excEnti=excEnti;
 } 
 }


public void addRow(){

       wrapperClass actWrap = new wrapperClass(new object1(),new List<object2>());  
        counter++;
        actWrap.counterWrap = counter; 
        wrapperList.add(actWrap);   

 }


 **public void addRowHex()
 {

 **//I dont know what to write here.//Please help.How to add a row inside of the first row added**

 }**
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below example should get you started on what you want to achieve. You can try it out separately as it uses the standard Account and Contact objects.

Page:

```
<apex:page controller="NestedTableLogicClass">
<apex:form >
<apex:commandButton value="Add Outer" action="{!addOuter}" rerender="panel"/>

<apex:outputPanel id="panel">
     <table>
     <apex:repeat value="{!myWrapperObject}" var="key">
      <tr>
        <td><apex:inputField value="{!myWrapperObject[key].objectVar.Name}" /></td>
        <td><apex:commandButton value="Add Inner Row" action="{!addInnerRow}" rerender="panel">
            <apex:param value="{!key}" name="row" assignTo="{!row}"/>
            </apex:commandButton>
            <table>
              <apex:repeat value="{!myWrapperObject[key].innerList}" var="innerListVar">
                <tr>
                  <td><apex:inputField value="{!innerListVar.lastName}" /></td>
                </tr>                
              </apex:repeat>
            </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
     </apex:repeat>
     </table>
</apex:outputPanel>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class NestedTableLogicClass{

  public Map<Integer,WrapperClass> myWrapperObject{get; set;}
  public Integer counter {get; set;}

  public Integer row {get; set;}

  public class WrapperClass{

    public List<Contact> innerList {get; set;}
    public Account objectVar{get; set;}

    public WrapperClass(){      
      this.innerList = new List<Contact>();
      this.objectVar = new Account();
    }
  }

  public NestedTableLogicClass(){
    counter = 0;
    myWrapperObject = new Map<Integer,WrapperClass>();

    /* Adding one outer row on page load*/
    addOuter(); 

  }

  public void addOuter(){
    counter++;
    myWrapperObject.put(counter,new WrapperClass());

    /* Add one inner row everytime an outer row is created */
    row = counter;
    addInnerRow();
  }

  public void addInnerRow(){
    myWrapperObject.get(row).innerList.add(new Contact());

  }
}
```

Comment: Hey AslamK.I just need to add both the rows on page load 1 outer and 1 inner i.e constructor.Can you please me with that  too..I tried but i am facing issue.?

Comment: @miku if you want to add one outer and inner row, simply call the two methods in the class constructor. I have updated the code accordingly.

Comment: Hey AslamK..Thanks this is working fine on Pageload..but if i want to again add a row second time..It is not coming inner row for second-time...I want whenever user click on addouter row..one row of outer and 1 inner row should automatically added..I am really stuck.Please help me.Thanks

Comment: I really need help on this Aslamk.I will really appreciate Thanks

Comment: Made the changes to code. Note the changes in the Constructor and the addOuter method. This should work for you.